# How to split data into train and test while stratifying on labels and preventing the same entity from appearing both?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset

I have a dataset like a graph below. I want to split it to train and test stratified on labels. At the same time, I don't want the same player to appear both.

For example, when I split it train:test=1:1.

| player | utterances | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | ... | 1 |
| John | ... | 1 |
| Mary | ... | 0 |
| Kethy | ... | 1 |
| Jack | ... | 1 |
| John | ... | 0 |
| John | ... | 1 |
| Mary | ... | 1 |

→

train(label 0 : label 1 = 1 : 3)

| player | utterances | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | ... | 1 |
| John | ... | 1 |
| John | ... | 0 |
| John | ... | 1 |

→

test(label 0 : label 1 = 1 : 3)

| player | utterances | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | ... | 0 |
| Mary | ... | 1 |
| Kethy | ... | 1 |
| Jack | ... | 1 |

Comment: Should train and test dataframes be of equal size ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, they shouldn't. I will split them 8:2.

Comment: Why scikit-learn's `train_test_split` with the `stratify` option won't do the job?

Comment: I don't want the same player to append in both train and test. If I use train_test_split, some of John's data probably appear in both train and test data. I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by tako0707's answer, I split my data into train,  valid, and test as follows.

Fortunately, train's, valid's and test's labels were almost stratified.

```
import pandas as pd

utterances, labels, players = [...], [...], [...]
df = pd.DaraFrame(
   dict(
     utterances=utterances,
     labels=labels,
     players=players,
   )
)

grouped = df.groupby('player')
groups = [grouped.get_group(x) for x in grouped.groups]
i = 0
train, train_size = [groups[i]], len(groups[i])

while train_size < len(labels) * 0.8:
    i += 1
    train_size += len(groups[i])
    train.append(groups[i])

test, test_size = [groups[i]], len(groups[i])
while test_size < len(labels)* 0.1:
    i += 1
    test_size += len(groups[i])
    test.append(groups[i])

valid, valid_size = [groups[i]], len(groups[i])
while valid_size < len(labels) * 0.1:
    i += 1
    valid_size += len(groups[i])
    valid.append(groups[i])

train.extend(groups[i+1:])

train, valid, test = pd.concat(train), pd.concat(valid), pd.concat(test)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

grouped = df.groupby('player')    
l=[grouped.get_group(x) for x in grouped.groups] # I have split dataframe via groupby

train,test =  train_test_split(l,test_size=0.5)
while len(pd.concat(train)) != len(pd.concat(test)):
    train,test =  train_test_split(l,test_size=0.5) # I've split it so that each contains an equal number of elements.

train = pd.concat(train)
test = pd.concat(test)
```